# Finite-state Machines: Number of Possible Answers

Tags: equation, state-machine

I'm wondering if there is an equation that gives the number of possible configurations of any given finite-state machine built to handle n inputs and m states.

How many possible solutions are there to any given process when using a finite-state machine to describe it?

I'm asking because I have a problem to solve using finite-state machines and I want to know if there is only one possible solution or many.

[Problem]

Build a finite state machine that produces an output of 1 if the input X, which can take the value 0 or 1, was 101 over the last three clock cycles.  X is updated each clock cycle.  There are four possible states S0, S1, S2, and S3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of configurations in a FSM is the number of states. It has no memory or context to differentiate being-in-state-X-now from being-in-state-X-then.

Are you talking about the potential paths through the states? i.e. the output sequence it emits as it transitions or, equivalently, the inputs which result in a termination state? These are potentially infinite, depending on the machine.

FSMs are very, very simple. If you're not sure whether you can use them, perhaps you don't have a clear description of the problem.

What is the actual problem?

Comment: I posted the problem above.

I'm just curious to know how many possible maps can be drawn to describe the finite state machine.  Infinite, one, or some number in between?

Comment: If this is homework, please tag it as such. There are four states, as you said. The answer to your questions is: how many graphs can be drawn with 4 vertices? There are 4*4 directed pairs so there are 2^(4*4) possible machines.

Comment: Ah, I see. I should have applied graph theory.  Thanks.